# Is it required to use Clean before Archive on Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, build

Is it required to use "Clean" before "Archive" command on Xode (on the project with many targets)? May you prove your answer? Xcode sometimes uses updated files on "Build" command and sometimes - not. Without any sense or logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not required, but it is definitely recommended. Xcode will use updated images with the same file name, but anything with more data like a local HTML will usually require a clean before archive. For example, if I update text in my local html, more than likely the text will update without a clean. Changing javascript however will require that I clean the project before the archive.

I hope this helps!